# What qualities of a crop are measured?

Tags: agriculture, research

The kind of crop I am interested in measuring is the cabbage.

I am currently in the midst of doing an academic research entitled "An Experimental Quantitative Study on Crops' Growth on Natural vs Artificial Lighting (CEA)" where I compare the crop quality cultivated under natural sunlight vs artificial lighting in CEA.

As it is a quantitative type, I am having trouble in quantifying the results and what proper quantitative methodologies do I have to employ to make the research successful.

Follow-up question:

After identifying the qualities of the crop I want to measure, what instruments are required, appropriate graphs to be illustrated for this kind of topic, and what methods should be employed to "measure a crop's quality"?

Edit: Made it more specific

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the crop type?  Does quality include speed of growth and total yield or are you only interested in the quality of the end result?

Comment: It depends on what you are after: tonnes of crop per hectare; water, fertilizer, pesticide, herbicide consumption per tonne of crop; tonnage of crop per lumens or lumen-hours of light; tonnage of crop per wavelength of light (color of light).

Comment: @f.thorpe I am interested in the quality of the end result of the product. Specifically, I want to measure cabbages' growth as an example.

Comment: @Fred I do now quite understand? I want to measure the quality of the crop but do not know what constitutes as a good quality and how to quantify crop quality. Can you elaborate on your statement so that I could learn more?

Comment: Tonnage per hectare is crop yield per area of planting - which produces more natural or artificial light. Is water or fertilizer uptake different for natural or artificial light? Lumens is the amount of light the plants receive. Is there a difference between lumens of natural or artificial light? Lumen-hours is the amount of light the plants get over a given time period. With artificial light is possible to illuminate the plant 24 h/day, but not with natural light. If you're comparing the two you have to have illuminate plants via artificial light for the same time duration that the ...

Comment: ... plants supplied with natural light are illuminated. Does the color of artificial light change the yield? Does red, orange, yellow, blue, or violet light change the yield, or any combination of these colors? I purposely omitted green light because most plants are green because they reflect green light, they don't absorb it.

Comment: Not sure why this question was migrated to meta.  I'm voting to reopen.  If it needs to be closed again please provide the reason for the author.  There is no agriculture stack exchange so I think this question is on-topic, though it needs work.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295119/where-can-i-ask-agriculture-related-questions-and-will-there-be-a-site-on-se-fo

Answer (score 1):

In the most simplistic sense, crop yield is the only thing that matters.  You could simply weigh all your usable product at the end of harvest.  Crop growth time is also an important consideration.  Calculate the total yield over a specified time period and let the biggest yield win!

Other than quantity, there are several aspects of crop quality that increase desirability:

- Taste: is the crop too bitter or characterized by mineral or fertilizer?
- Crop Hardiness: is the crop more susceptible to disease or other [cultivation problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabbage#Cultivation_problems)
- Growing Requirements: do the crops require more water or nutrient than others?
- Sustainability: How does pesticide/fertilizer use and high crop density affect soil quality?  Do you need to rotate crops or go fallow?
- Marketability: Do you have the best [variety](https://smallfarmersjournal.com/cabbage/), organic certification, or other features that raise the price value of your crop.

Farmers regularly inspect their crop and soil for disease and desirability.  They also keep track of how much water, nutrient, and chemical is applied.  Finally, they weigh (or count) the final crop yield and calculate total sales.

Light influence on crop quality is a common agricultural question, and you should use prior work in the community as an initial model for your experiment.  For instance, a quick search turned up [Photosynthesis under artificial light: the shift in primary and secondary metabolism (Darko et al, 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3949401/), but I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: If I understood correctly, If I want to compare between using natural and artificial lighting , then crop yield and crop growth time would be the best to measure?

Comment: You should also research what artificial lights are best for your crop type and probably use several artificial lighting configurations in your experiment.